# D3 js reversing transition on click

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

```
d3.select(this)
.transition()
.attr(‘d’,d3.arc().innerRadius(radius*0.7).outerRadius(radius*1.08));
```

I was able to achieve a transition on click event using above code
Now I want to reverse this transition to its original state 
On click 
Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: what was the `d` attribute's value before then?

Comment: @georgeawg. D contains endangle:2.827433 index:2 padangle0: startangle: 1.88495

Comment: You said what the bound data is, but not what the value of the attribute. Is the initial path also generated by d3.arc from data?